# Android splash screen not showing the full image

Tags: android

"I'm trying to add the splash screen I created, but there's this rounded rectangle on Android, how do I remove it?"

[image]

Comment: I had the same problem few months ago. This answer helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69894720/new-splash-screen-is-shown-cut-in-a-circle-shape

Comment: Can we see your layout?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are using `<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">` in your splash theme style in themes.xml. What you can do is replacing it with `<item name="android:windowBackground">`.

`<item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">` is using android new splash api after android 12, you can find reference on [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen), so alternative solution is to keep your splash image size within the Splash screen dimensions mentioned in above reference link